# Input variables in a sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I wrote following sql query in order to implement radius search. Seems this segment is not working. I think its a syntax error.

```html
$statement = "SELECT store,address,phone,lat,log,zipcode,city,state, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(". $lat .") ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( log ) - radians(". $lng .") ) + sin( radians(". $lat .") ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM geoinfo WHERE (zipcode = '$search_text' OR city = '$search_text' OR state = '$search_text') AND (distance < '$radius')";

$numberofstores = $resultstore = mysqli_query($conn, $statement);
```

Please help.

Comment: Why you do not add the error measseg if it is a syntax error? You should learn about prepared statements.

Comment: use error_Reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: You cannot use a derived column alias in a WHERE clause. Either change "WHERE distance" to "HAVING distance" or, better, write out the whole distance formula longhand again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this by changing your WHERE distance to HAVING distance, this is because you can't use a derived column alias in an SQL WHERE clause.